# Htaccess Internal Rewrite with arg + uri

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I'm trying to perform an internal rewrite of example.com/abc to example.com/?//abc where 'abc' can by any string.

Tried the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$  /?//$1 [L,QSA,NC,PT]
```

However this is not redirecting as expected. From the logs, I can see the following entries:

```
applying pattern '^(\\w+)/?$' to uri 'abc
rewrite 'abc' -> '/?//abc'
split uri=/?//abc -> uri=/, args=//abc
internal redirect with / [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
applying pattern '^(\\w+)/?$' to uri ''
```

Not sure, why it's splitting the pattern to uri and arg based on '?'. Can any one  help

Comment: I've now managed to redirect the url using the following rule: 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$" 
RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?//$1/ [L,R] This is now redirecting to the desired URL, but the url is changing in browser. Any ideas how to maintain the same URL

Comment: Can anyone shed some light, please?

Answer (score 0):

Since your second example works, remove the `R` flag. It sends the redirect to the browser.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?//$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Tried removing R flag, but now the redirect don't work. Enabled rewrite logging for apache and following are noted:
++++++++
    applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'abc'
    rewrite 'abc' -> '/index.html?//abc'
    split uri=/index.html?//abc -> uri=/index.html, args=//abc
    trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/player with /
    internal redirect with /index.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
    strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/player/index.html -> index.html
    applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.html'
++++

Comment: Ok, can you answer these questions? **1.** Where is `index.html`? Is it `/var/www/html/player/index.html`? **2.** Where is this `.htaccess`? Is it `/var/www/html/player/.htaccess`?

Comment: **1**. Yes, index.html is in /var/www/html/player folder
**2**. Yes, .htaccess is in /var/www/html/player folder

Comment: Sorry, @Anonymous Still this is not working.
Now, the URL stays, but the page is not redirecting. Please see the logs:

strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/player/abc -> abc
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'abc'
rewrite 'abc' -> 'index.html?//abc/'
 split uri=index.html?//abc/ -> uri=index.html, args=//abc/
add per-dir prefix: index.html -> /var/www/html/player/index.html
strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/player/index.html -> /index.html
internal redirect with /index.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix:/var/www/html/player/index.html->index.html

Comment: @mintumohan Do you have anything else in your .htaccess? It looks like a conflict

Comment: Nothing else. Only the htaccess code you've mentioned

Comment: @mintumohan What do you mean when you say "the URL stays, but the page is not redirecting"? It’s an internal rewrite, so you won’t see a redirect in the browser

Comment: What I need is the URL should remain same after the redirection. That is after the redirection, URL should be example.com/abc.

Comment: Sorry, but I won’t be able to figure this out without looking at the server. The .htaccess should be working, so it could be a problem with the index.php file or something else. Good luck figuring it out.